# Android Studio Build APK Error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-multidex

I'm programming an application and when I tried to build APK I got these 2 ugly errors, which I have never seen.

[image]

First error I tried to figure out by link which is there but with no result and the second error, I have no really no idea. Thanks for all help.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
```

}

Comment: you have multidex issue, check this link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: 1) Please show your `build.gradle` - You likely have too many dependencies (such as Google Play Services you don't need); 2) That error message tells you exactly what link to go to in order to solve the problem